# T-SQL XPath query including Parent

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

This problem keeps messing around with my Friday afternoon:

I have this XML:

```
declare @xml as XML
set @xml =
'<fields>
  <field>
    <id>1</id>
    <items>
      <item>
        <name>name1_1</name>
        <value>value1_1</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <name>name1_2</name>
        <value>value1_2</value>
      </item>
    </items>
  </field>
  <field>
    <id>2</id>
    <items>
      <item>
        <name>name2_1</name>
        <value>value2_1</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <name>name2_2</name>
        <value>value2_2</value>
      </item>
    </items>
  </field>
</fields>'
```

Using T-SQL and XPath, I need a query to get this result:

```
id   name     value
1    name1_1  value1_1
1    name1_2  value1_2
2    name2_1  value2_1
2    name2_2  value2_2
```

I'm getting name and value with:

```
SELECT c.value('name[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') name,
       c.value('value[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') value
FROM @xml.nodes('fields/field/items/item') t(c)
```

...but how to insert the parent column "id"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own code uses `.nodes()` to get a derived table from repeating elements. In your case there are two levels of repeating elements:

- many fields and within each field
- many items

You have to use `.nodes()` twice:

```
SELECT fld.value(N'(id/text())[1]',N'int') AS FieldID
      ,itm.value(N'(name/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ItemName
      ,itm.value(N'(value/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ItemValue
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/fields/field') AS A(fld)
OUTER APPLY A.fld.nodes(N'items/item') AS B(itm);
```

The first `.nodes()` comes back with XML fragments, one for each field, the second node is called for each of these field-fragments to pick their items.

Use `OUTER APPLY` if there might be fields without `<item>` nodes and `CROSS APPLY` when you do not want to see fields without `<item>` nodes (similar to `LEFT JOIN` vs `INNER JOIN`)

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: there is only one `id` element per `field`.

```
SELECT c.value('../../id[1]', 'int') id,
       c.value('name[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') name,
       c.value('value[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') value
FROM @xml.nodes('fields/field/items/item') t(c)
```

The `..` operator means "select parent of node" in XPATH. So the query will select the parent of `item`, then the parent of `items`, then the first child node `id`

Comment: Although this might work, backward navigation (`../../id`) is not the best choice...